# Building 64-bit Python extensions with f2py on Windows

Tags: numpy, mingw, f2py, python-extensions, mingw-w64

I'm attempting to build a Python extension from Fortran source using Numpy's `f2py.py` script. I'm following the steps from http://www.scipy.org/F2PY_Windows ([web archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20130130054833/http://scipy.org/F2PY_Windows)). My system is Windows 7 64-bit, and I primarily use Python 2.7.3 [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]. I have Numpy-MKL 1.7.1, from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy

Here is what I've tried:

1. Choose a Fortran compiler. Since I'm using 64-bit Python, a 64-bit Fortran compiler is required. From [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/), I've tried a few of the personal builds.
2. Open a new `cmd.exe` shell, and edit the path to where I extracted the GCC compilers, i.e.:

   - `set PATH=%PATH%;c:\gnu\mingw64\bin`
   - `set C_INCLUDE_PATH=C:\gnu\mingw64\include`
3. Try the `f2py.py` build with this command:

   `C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Python27\Scripts\f2py.py -c --fcompiler=gnu95 --compiler=mingw32 -lmsvcr90 -m foo foo.f90`

The output is (removing noise lines at `<--snip-->`):

```
running build
<--snip-->
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'foo.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
        Block: foo
                        Block: hello
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "foo"...
                Constructing wrapper function "hello"...
                  hello()
        Wrote C/API module "foo" to file "c:\users\mtoews\appdata\local\temp\tmpjr6qop\src.win-amd64-2.7\foomodule.c"
  adding 'c:\users\mtoews\appdata\local\temp\tmpjr6qop\src.win-amd64-2.7\fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding 'c:\users\mtoews\appdata\local\temp\tmpjr6qop\src.win-amd64-2.7' to include_dirs.
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.c -> c:\users\mtoews\appdata\local\temp\tmpjr6qop\src.win-amd64-2.7
copying C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\f2py\src\fortranobject.h -> c:\users\mtoews\appdata\local\temp\tmpjr6qop\src.win-amd64-2.7
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
Looking for python27.dll
Building import library (arch=AMD64): "C:\Python27\libs\libpython27.a" (from C:\Windows\system32\python27.dll)
Building msvcr library: "C:\Python27\libs\libmsvcr90.a" (from C:\Windows\winsxs\amd64_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.21022.8_none_750b37ff97f4f68b\msvcr90.dll)
Cannot build msvcr library: "msvcr90d.dll" not found
customize Mingw32CCompiler
customize Mingw32CCompiler using build_ext
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable c:\gnu\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
Found executable c:\gnu\mingw64\bin\gfortran.exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Scripts\f2py.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
<--snip-->
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\gnu.py", line 331, in get_libraries
    raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64")
NotImplementedError: Only MS compiler supported with gfortran on win64
```

Note that the first time this is run, three new files are build in `C:\Python27\libs`:

- `libmsvcr90.a`
- `libpython27.a`
- `python27.def`

Do I need to install anything else? Do I need to provide other options to `f2py`? More generally speaking, it possible to build an extension for MSVC-build Python from GNU compilers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that the solution is to just comment out the exception line. See this [blog post](http://scientificcomputingco.blogspot.com.au/2013/02/f2py-on-64bit-windows-python27.html).

Comment: That appears to work. Also, I had to remove a `-lmsvcr90` flag to f2py.

Comment: Same for me, except I wasn't running f2py directly, it was being called internally via numpy distutils.  This post helped me out (and note to delete the `libmsvcr90.a` file that got generated): http://mechaos.de/wordpress/?p=303#comment-169

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar error when trying to install ggplot with

```
pip install -U ggplot
```

The solution was found here: https://github.com/obspy/obspy/wiki/Installation-via-Anaconda

> Anaconda for Windows ships with C and Fortran compilers, however
>   compiling on a 64bit Windows may require a small patch by changing
>   line no. 331 in
>   AnacondaInstallDir\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\fcompiler\gnu.py
>   to pass #raise NotImplementedError("Only MS compiler supported with
>   gfortran on win64").

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in a future release, a [**discussed**](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3405) and [**changed**](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/commit/acd873633a9c7017571834ca9d266ed5756d73ed).

It looks like this change did not make it to the 1.9.x maintenance branch, but in the master tree and whatever version is after.